# How to turn off the large output suppression

Tags: matrix, front-end, output-formatting

I am currently calculating some large matrix operations.
The calculation results [image]in some huge size matrices, and the output is sometimes suppressed as this

However, I really don't want it to be shown like this, so I click "show all", then the program stuck forever.

But when the output is just a full matrix, it usually doesn't have this problem.

How can I make Mathematica show the result without any suppression? Any command to that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: But that would be equivalent to what happens when you press "Show all" (ie MMA gets stuck forever), so why would you want that? It's the rendering of your full output that takes forever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mathematica has written nice [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ShortenLongOutputs.html) about shortening the output and its options.

### Summary

In general change `$OutputSizeLimit` to increase the limit Mathematica shorten the output.

For specific cases, use `InputForm`.

but be aware in both cases you will have performance penalties.